# Dynamically add choicechip on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add ChoiceChip/InputChip dynamically inside a Container.
I'm selecting the choices from a list and it's adding inside the container. But I'm getting horizontal overflow error while adding the choices. I've used Wrap widget but it's not working. I want to use wrap so that the next selected chip is on the next line. Can anyone please help?

```
List<Widget> _specialWidget = List<Widget>();
                         DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              hint: Text(Strings.searchJob),
                              value: _jobTitle == null
                                  ? null
                                  : Lists.jobCatagories[_jobTitle],
                              items: Lists.jobCatagories.map((String value) {
                                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: new Text(value),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _jobTitle =
                                      Lists.jobCatagories.indexOf(value);
                                  _specialWidget.add(Special());
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

The chips are adding here which comes from a StatefulWidget

```
                     Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: List.generate(
                            _specialWidget.length,
                            (i) {
                              return _specialWidget[i];
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

```
class Special extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpecialState createState() => _SpecialState();
}

class _SpecialState extends State<Special> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        InputChip(
          label: Text(
            _jobTitle == null ? null : Lists.jobCatagories[_jobTitle],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KD8M.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace a `Row` with in your code with a `Wrap`.

```dart
 Container(
    child: Row( // REPLACE THIS WITH Wrap
    children: List.generate(
      _specialWidget.length,
      (i) {
        return _specialWidget[i];
      },
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

Currently your code `Wrap`s single widget and adds it as the `Row` children which defeats the purpose of the `Wrap`. `Wrap` should replace a `Row` in your case, because, as you already know, it's task is to break the line of widgets if they  overflow -- just like `Text` widget will do with a long string.

Here's more info about the `Wrap` widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for describing the issue. Have a nice day.